# NSFetchedResultsController and Swift3

Tags: nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift3, ios10, xcode8

So before when I was in swift 2.2 I had me code basically built like this:

```
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lists")
    let sortDesc1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "favorite", ascending: false)
    let sortDesc2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc3 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc1, sortDesc2, sortDesc3]

    return fetchRequest
}

func getFRC() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: doc, sectionNameKeyPath: "favorite", cacheName: nil)

    return frc
}
```

I think that is how it used to look. But now with Swift 3, it looks similar but slightly different

```
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<Lists>?

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Lists> {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Lists> = Lists.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Lists>
    let sortDesc1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "favorite", ascending: false)
    let sortDesc2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc3 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc1, sortDesc2, sortDesc3]

    return fetchRequest
}

func getFRC() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Lists> {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "favorite" , cacheName: nil)

    return frc!
}
```

From what I understand, a lot of these changes were to get away from using strings to identify your entity when you already have a class made for that entity. But I'm wondering if I should be changing my code in the getFRC function since it is identifying the section Key with a string still. Is this still correct, or is there a newer swift 3 way of doing this too? And I guess that question would apply to how I'm identifying my NSSortDescriptors too, those are still strings as well.